# Spring JdbcTemplate's queryForList() with many args is not readable; SQLQuery don't give me list with column names

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, plsql, jdbctemplate

Note: This may be a simple question but I can't find a short way to make it clear. So, sorry for this long question.

In a project I am responsible, I use Spring 2.5, Hibernate 3.3.2 as middleware and Oracle database. As database is related to many other projects, some queries as really very complicated and I can't get a solution with Hibernate's solutions (HQL, Criteria, etc...). So I feel more comfortable with JdbcTemplate's queryForX() methods, as an example;

```
String sql = "select * from myTable";
jdbc.queryForList(sql);
```

Sure there are mostly "where" conditions and params indeed:

```
jdbc.querForList(sql, new Object[]{obj1,obj2,obj3 /* and many more arguments... */})
```

In this case, I must write question marks "?" for my parameters, so my SQL query string turns out some messy and hard to read; something like this:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2, t1.col, --...some cols , 
    sum(nvl(some_col1,?)-nvl(other_col2,?)) over (partition by col1,col2,col3,col4) sum_of_cols 
from weird_table t1, another_table t2
where t1.col20=? and sum_of_cols>? and t1.col3=t2.col3 --and many ?'s...
and not exists (
    select ? from boring_table t3 where -- many ?'s
)
--group by  and order by order by etc
```

So now, which question mark is for which parameter? It is obvious but hard to read. But there are some other solutions for binded params like:

```
select * from a_table t where t.col1= :col1 and t.col2= :col2 -- and many more ":param"s
```

For this type query, we can write if it were Hibernate:

```
Query q = hibernateTemplate.createQuery();
q.setString("col1","a value");
q.setInteger("col2", 3);
```

I think it is more readable and easy to understand which value is what. I know I can do this with SQLQuery;

```
SQLQuery sq = hibernateTemplate.createSQLQuery();
/* same as above setInteger() etc. */
```

But this `sq.list()` gives me a list without a column name. so I have a basic array which is difficult to use:

```
[[1,2,"a"],[1,2,"b"], ...]
```

But with `queryForList()` I get better one:

```
[{COL1=1,COL2=2,COL3="a"},{COL1=1,COL2=2,COL3="b"},...]
```

So if I use `queryForList()`, I must write a very messy params Object;
or I use `SQLQuery` and then I have to get my list without a map as column names.

Is there a simple solution with mapped list using more readable param setting (like query.setX()) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can use [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) to do just that

Heres a sample

```
    String query = "INSERT INTO FORUMS (FORUM_ID, FORUM_NAME, FORUM_DESC)
 VALUES (:forumId,:forumName,:forumDesc)";
    Map namedParameters = new HashMap();
    namedParameters.put("forumId", Integer.valueOf(forum.getForumId()));
    namedParameters.put("forumName", forum.getForumName());
    namedParameters.put("forumDesc", forum.getForumDesc());
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(query, namedParameters);
```

You check the complete example with the source code in the below link

[Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate Tutorial](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-named-parameter-jdbc-template.html)

Comment: NOTE: It's cleaner to use Spring's MapSqlParameterSource for setting your parameters. It gives support for datatypes by allowing namedParameters.put("forumName", forum.getForumName(), String.class);

Comment: Thank you @ninn, I checked it too and I want to make a little correction for your code. I am editing actual answer with your addition.